# Jquery Toggle Prevent default on a link

Tags: jquery

I am displaying links on a website.

When the user clicks on the link, I don't want them to go the URL immediately. Instead, an inline pop-up box* should appear with a disclaimer. The user can then click on the link a second time to go to the URL (and this will also hide the disclaimer).

I know you can use [Prevent Default](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to disable the default action of a link (so it doesn't take the user anywhere).

And I know you can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide a pop-up box.

However, I am not sure how you can toggle prevent default.

Here is my jQuery code **(JS Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/HZsQv/2/))**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";
        $(".ui-popbox a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("[class^='ui-popbox-']").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

By "inline pop-up box" I am referring to a box that appears inside an HTML document. I don't mean a pop-up window.

Comment: You can create a separate handler function that contains the event.preventDefault() call, and then just bind and unbind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a data object into the event handler to check if the disclaimer is popped or not in jQuery as follow:

```
$(".ui-popbox a").click({popped: false}, function (e) {
    if (!e.data.popped) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("[class^='ui-popbox-']").fadeToggle();
        e.data.popped = true;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HZsQv/6/

The value of the object will be kept between events.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am just trying to understand how this code works: You create a variable called Popped which has a default value of false. When the link is clicked, you set this variable to true. When the variable is set to true, none of the code in the if statement will run. Is that correct? Thanks!